# How to remove li inside existing ul using class Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With help I managed to create add and remove from existing list.

When I add the desired text it gets the `id` so I can remove it later if I want to. The problem with the already existing list is that it can't be removed if I don't set the manual `id`.
How can I make so when I click on the element it gets `<strong>` and gets a `class` and when I click remove it removes. Can you point me in the right direction?

```js
function addItem() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute('id', txt.value);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function removeItem() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
  var item = document.getElementById(txt.value);
  ul.removeChild(item);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<button onclick="addItem()">Add</button>
<button onclick="removeItem()">Remove</button>

<ul id="list">
  <li id="element1">element1</li>
  <li>element2</li>
  <li>element3</li>
  <li>element4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not clear your idea behind item removal. Can you shed some light? If you ask me, in order to *remove* an already added item - such item should have a *Remove* button next to it.

Comment: Also, inside a text input one can add spaces. The input value goes to the LI item as ID. But an ID with spaces is an invalid ID... etc etc. Your current idea has some serious flaws.

Comment: I apologize. At the moment if I add element "apple" I have to input apple in the text and click on remove to be removed. I want to be able to click in the element then click on remove and it removes.

Comment: I want it to be simple so I won't use spaces when inputing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need IDs at all.
On LI creation append a Remove button. The button, when clicked, will lookup for its closest LI element and remove it.
Doing it this way, and not relating input value to IDs - you can enter any text you want, even with spaces:

```js
const $add = $("#add"),
      $txt = $("#txt"),
      $list = $("#list");

function newListItem() {

  const $remove = $("<button>", {
    text: "×",
    title: "Remove item",
    on: {
      click() {
        $(this).closest("li").remove();
      }
    }
  });

  return $("<li>", {
    text: $txt.val(),
    append: $remove, 
    prependTo: $list,
    ready() {
      $txt.val(""); // Clear input value once LI is ready
    }
  });
}

$add.on("click", newListItem)
```

```css
li button {border-radius:50%; border:0; margin-left:10px; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button id="add">Add</button>
<ul id="list"></ul>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to highlight a desired li and have a single REMOVE button, a nice way would be to assign a `.is-selected` class on LI click, and on Remove click - remove only the one that has the `is-selected` classname:

```js
const $add = $("#add"),
      $remove = $("#remove"),
      $txt = $("#txt"),
      $list = $("#list");

function newListItem() {
  return $("<li>", {
    text: $txt.val(),
    prependTo: $list,
    ready() {
       $txt.val(""); // Clear input value once LI is ready
    }
  });
}

// Manage LI selections for Removal
$list.on("click", "li", function() {
  $list.find("li").not(this).removeClass("is-selected");
  $(this).addClass("is-selected");
});

function removeListItem() {
  const $selected = $list.find("li.is-selected");
  if(!$selected.length) return alert("Select an item to remove");
  $selected.remove();
}

$add.on("click", newListItem);
$remove.on("click", removeListItem);
```

```css
li.is-selected{ outline: 2px solid #0bf; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
<ul id="list">
  <li>Select me and click Remove</li>
  <li>I'm another to-do item</li>
</ul>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

To have to scroll up the list just to hit the Remove button seems to me a bad UI, instead here's how I'd approach this task, basically a mix of example 1 and 2:

```js
const $add = $("#add"),
  $txt = $("#txt"),
  $list = $("#list"),
  $remove = $("<button>", {
    text: "Remove",
    on: {
      click() {
        const $li = $(this).closest('li.is-selected');
        $(this).detach();
        $li.remove();
      }
    }
  });

function newListItem() {
  return $("<li>", {
    text: $txt.val(),
    prependTo: $list,
    ready() { $txt.val(""); } // Clear input value once LI is ready
  });
}

// Manage LI selections for Removal
$list.on("click", "li", function() {
  $list.find("li").not(this).removeClass("is-selected");
  $(this).addClass("is-selected").append( $remove ); // Append our Remove button
});

$add.on("click", newListItem)
```

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

li.is-selected {
  background: rgba(100,200,255,0.2);
}

li.is-selected button { /* Show Remove button on LI select */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button id="add">Add</button>
<ul id="list">
  <li>Select me and click Remove</li>
  <li>I'm another to-do item</li>
</ul>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great and I don't want to be rude by any means. I want to be able to mark any element I want and then deleting it with a remove button.

Comment: @NenaPece humm, I think I understand, let me add another example

Comment: @NenaPece does this helps?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I can change mark style with CSS. I was struggling so hard with this, only practice will help in this case. Thank you very much.

Comment: one more question. If I add elements manually(in the code) can I remove them with that method too?

Comment: @NenaPece In the case you prepopulate LIs manually - see my edited code (2nd example)

Comment: To improve the above code, I'd make the `Remove` button initially hidden. Once one selects a LI element - than I'd show the button. - But again - For a better UI, I'd make a button next to a is-selected LI element. Reason: imagine you have a list of many items. Select an item and than scroll up just to hit the Remove button is silly :)

Comment: @NenaPece take a peak at the third example. Happy coding.

Comment: Can you please explain me those constants. I understand const MY_CONSTANT = "some-value"; , but why # before add(const $add = $("#add"))? Is it possible to remove the const and just use $("#add") ? I know this is just a basic question, but I rather ask than don't know to explain it.

Comment: If I understand it right this is just to make it more simple and "shorter" code?

Comment: Since `const $add = $("#add")` is used to store in memory (cache) our `#add` element, later on you can reuse `$add` instead of querying the entire DOM looking for the same element again. But since in our JS code we reference to `$add` only once, you *can* remove the variable and go directly for `$("#add").on("click", newListItem)` instead of the current `$add.on("click", newListItem)`